# Replace text in file with incremented text

Tags: bash, ssh, replace, scripting

I have a file in the directory with this text

```
VERSION_NUMBER: 1
```

I need to get the value of `VERSION_NUMBER` convert it to number and make `n+1` and write it to a variable, for example variable `test`.

How I can do this using `sed`

Comment: It's really hard with `sed`.  It's really easy with `awk`.  Why do you want to use `sed`?

Comment: I can take a look to every option. @WilliamPursell

Comment: is this the *only* text in the file ... just this one line?  what do you mean by 'get this variable'? are you looking to define/set a variable named `VERSION_NUMBER`? or can the value go into any (shell) variable? do you need to update the file with the new value (`n+1`)?

Comment: I need to extract the number from `VERSION_NUMBER` and write it to any variable to use it @markp-fuso

Comment: For your use case, are you saying you just want to assign the value of `2` to a variable?  Or are you also wanting to edit the file?

Comment: For now just to assign 2. @WilliamPursell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- there's only one line in the input file
- there's no need to verify that the value following the `:` is a number
- no need to update the file with the new value

Input file:

```
$ cat myfile
VERSION_NUMBER: 1
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ x=$(sed -En 's/^.*: (.*)$/\1/p' myfile)
$ ((x++))
$ echo "${x}"
2
```

One `cut` idea:

```
$ x=$(cut -d: -f2 myfile)
$ ((x++))
$ echo "${x}"
2
```

Same thing with `awk`:

```
$ x=$(awk '{print $2}' myfile)
$ ((x++))
$ echo "${x}"
2
```

---

---

In a comment OP has asked how to update the file with the new value.

Since we're only talking about a single line the following ...

```
$ echo "VERSION_NUMBER: ${x}" > myfile
```

... is probably going to be easier/simpler than running another `sed` or `awk` command to overwrite the current file.

Comment: try to run this in gitlab.ci

and get this `jobs:step-publish-nuget-package:script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep`


maybe because `x=$(sed -En 's/^.*: (.*)$/\1/p' myfile)` not string

Comment: these are (relatively) basic commands that do exactly what you've stipulated in your question; it sounds (to me) like you're not at a `bash` terminal in which case I'd suggest you update the question with more details on what you're trying to do (eg, the full command you just ran along with the full output/error message)

Comment: Got this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

at `x=$(sed -En 's/^.*: (.*)$/\1/p' myfile)`

Comment: this is how I use it ` x=$(sed -n 's/^.*:\ (.*)$/\1/p' ./package-version.txt)`

Comment: with awk all okay

Comment: Okay, if I want to update file with this new value, what I need to do?

Comment: you typed the `sed` command in wrong ... instead of `sed -n` you need `sed -En`; hmmm, you're also showing an 'extra' backslash; try cutting-n-pasting from the answer in to your console to eliminate typos ... ?

Comment: I tried with awk and it easier and all working great. How I can update file with updated variable?

Comment: @EugeneSukh added a section to the answer re: updating the file